# How to send events/messages to specific clients in node.js using Socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

i'm working on a Node.js app in which we are using socket.io for sending and receiving events/messages to clients. Initially it is sending events to clients using the following statement.

> io.sockets.emit('SequenceLoad', data);

But now i want to send events only to specific clients using client specific sockets. I have searched alot regarding this, found some ways but none of them seems to work, found on various SO posts.

Here is the code that i have tried:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
var socketsCollection = [];
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  //Saving socket id's for sending events to specific sockets based on their ids
  socketsCollection.push(socket.id);
  socket.on('SequenceLoadServer', function (data) {
     // logger.info('Socket Server | Event: sequenceLoadServer with socket server. \n Data:'+ data);
     console.log("In APP.js for SequenceLoadServer event");
     console.log("Socket Id :" + socket.id);
     var socketId = null;
     setTimeout(function () {
        for (var item of socketsCollection) {
           if(item == socket.id){
              socketId= item;
              break;   
           }
        }
        console.log("Socket after searching Id :" + socketId);
        io.sockets.emit('SequenceLoad', data);   -> This works at the moment

        //Tried the following ways as well but none of them worked 

        //io.sockets.connected[socketId].emit('SequenceLoad', data);
        //io.sockets.socket(socketId).emit('SequenceLoad', data); 
        //io.to(socketId).emit('SequenceLoad', data);
        //io.to('/#' + socketId).emit('SequenceLoad', data);
        //io.to(`${socketId}`).emit('SequenceLoad', data);

     }, 1000 * 3);

  });
}
```

Version of socket.io in my project:

```
"socket.io": "^2.2.0",
"socket.io-client": "^2.2.0"
```

Any help would great, correct me if i'm doing wrong because i'm new to it. Thanks

Comment: How do you want to select a particular `socket`/client? Via its `id`?

Comment: @NickParsons yes

Answer (score 1):

Given you have the socket instance, you can send to a specific client directly by:

```
io.to(`${socket.id}`).emit(...);
```

See [Emit cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/)

Comment: You can see in my post that i'm already doing it but it is not working.

Comment: @Harry.Naeem that doesn't mean it's not the correct way to do this - also have you looked at my answer closely? I'm not using the ID you fetch from the array, I'm using the `socket.id` directly (this would be the same difference due to how closures work). I believe the issue is your loop / ID fetch isn't giving you the correct ID, try using the `socket.id` directly, I'd fully expect it to work.

Comment: I didn't said it is wrong way but i have tried this. My loop is giving me the correct id that i have saved and i'm using logs to see the socket id before emiting the data. But anyhow i will take a look into it as well

Comment: Yes i have tried this thing, but still it doesn't work